# Using the kube-prometheus-stack helm chart, how can I see only the pods I want in a particular namespace as targets in Promethes?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, metrics, kube-prometheus-stack

Using the **kube-prometheus-stack** helm chart, I want to scrape the metrics of only 3 pods out of 6 pods in the **app** namespace in K8S with **Prometheus**.

In this context, I added the **additionalScrapeConfigs** code blog to the **values.yaml** file and added the following change.

```
additionalScrapeConfigs:
  - job_name: new-app-api-metrics
    scrape_interval: 15s
    metrics_path: /app-api-metrics
    honor_labels: true
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: endpoints
      namespaces:
        names:
          - app
    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
      separator: ;
      regex: http
      replacement: $1
      action: keep
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
      separator: ;
      regex: (.*)
      target_label: namespace
      replacement: $1
      action: replace
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
      separator: ;
      regex: new-app-api-.*
      target_label: pod
      replacement: $1
      action: replace
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
      separator: ;
      regex: new-app-api-.*
      target_label: service
      replacement: $1
      action: replace
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
      separator: ;
      regex: new-app-api-.*
      target_label: job
      replacement: ${1}
      action: replace
    - separator: ;
      regex: new-app-api-.*
      target_label: endpoint
      replacement: http
      action: replace
```

Then I added the **additionalServiceMonitors** code blog to the **values.yaml** file and added the following change.

```
additionalServiceMonitors:
- name: new-app-api-metrics
  additionalLabels:
    release: new-service-test-kube-prometheus-stack
    app.kubernetes.io/name: new-app-api
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: new-app-api
  jobLabel: new-app-api-metrics
  namespaceSelector: 
    matchNames: 
      - new-app-api
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: new-app-api
      app.kubernetes.io/name: new-app-api
      release: new-service-test-kube-prometheus-stack
  endpoints: 
    - port: "3000"
      interval: 15s
      path: /app-api-metrics
      scheme: http
```

But when I look at the **Prometheus UI**, the **new-config-app-api** pods in the **app** namespace are also seen as targets, besides the one I want to pull their metrics from.

However, I just want to scrape the metrics of **3** **new-app-api** pods from **6 pods** in the **app** namespace.

What other changes do I need to make?

Comment: Are the pods you don't want to scrape actually annotated with keys that tell prometheus to scrape?

Comment: @jordanm I created additionalScrapeConfigs section in kube-prometheus-stack Helmchart values.ayml file. And I defined a new job. I tried to filter using regex but it didn't work. What other method can I use?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to filter the **pods** I wanted by adding the following **source_labels** to the **relabel_configs** section in **job_name**.

```
     - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_app_kubernetes_io_name,       __meta_kubernetes_service_labelpresent_app_kubernetes_io_name]
      separator: ;
      regex: (new-app-api);true
      replacement: $1
      action: keep
```